# Why doesn't type() work in if statements in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, input, types, conditional-statements

```
user_input = int(input('Enter input: '))

if type(user_input) == "<class 'int'>":
    print('This is a integer.')
```

The code above outputs nothing to the console. I am just confused because it is very simple and looks like it should work.

I've tried removing the int() in the input line which output nothing, I understand this because user_input turns into a string but I do not understand why it outputs nothing when user_input is defined as an integer.

Comment: use `isinstance(user_input,int)`. Don't confuse a type with a string representation. In this particular case the type check is pointless. If the line above doesn't throw an error then of course `user_input` is an int. A better way to do what you seem to want to do is to use a `try ... except` block around the line that tries to convert a string to an int.

Comment: Because no type can ever be equal to any string, for the same reason that no integer can ever be equal to any string. Types themselves have their own type.

Comment: (Some people will suggest that relying on try-except is bad and you should use string methods like `isdigit`. Those people are wrong - those methods check character properties, not whether a string can be parsed as an int. You'll fail on inputs like `-3`, because `-` isn't a digit. Trying to get the check right manually is needlessly error-prone compared to just letting `int` handle it, and the situation gets even worse if you're trying to parse floats instead of ints.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix

That is because `type(user_input)` returns a `type`, not a string, don't confuse yourself with what you see printed and the real thing. When you print something you only see a **representation** of the thing. Only if it's a string you can copy and compare it directly

```
print(type(type(user_input)))  # <class 'type'>
```

So you well understand, this is how it would work using `type`

```
if str(type(user_input)) == "<class 'int'>":
    print('This is a integer.')

if type(user_input) == int:
    print('This is a integer.')

if type(user_input) is int:
    print('This is a integer.')
```

#### Improve

The prefered way should be

```
if isinstance(user_input, int):
    print('This is a integer.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're comparing it to the wrong thing. if you did "type(user_input) == int" your program should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `isinstance` method as mentioned above or just directly compare to the `int` like:

```
user_input = int(input('Enter input: '))

if type(user_input) is int:
   print('This is a integer.')
```

Comment: Same, `type` doesn't return a string, see my answer

Comment: isen´t int here an object of class int?

Comment: It is, but here was quotes around , so its a string, not class int